# Object Does not contain a defination for Database and no extension method Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

i have to declare a function for Crystal Report Viewer in C#, but it shows me some error like; (Object Does not contain a definition for Database and no extension method 'Database' excepting a first argument of type 'object' could be find (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?))my code is given below

```
 public static object ConnectionForReports(object objReport)
{
        SqlConnection cn = null;
        cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CMScon);
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = null;
        **logOnInfo = objReport.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo;**
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = cn.DataSource;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = cn.Database;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "SQLadmin";
        **objReport.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);**
        return objReport;
}
```

The Error shows in Highlighted line.

Comment: Start reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declare a simple method in my class

```
 public static object ConnForReport(ReportDocument objReport)
{
SqlConnection cn = null;
cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CMScon);
CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = null;
logOnInfo = objReport.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo;
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = cn.DataSource;
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = cn.Database;
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "SQLadmin";
objReport.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
return objReport;
}
```

then i use this method on my button click event like this:

```
protected void CmdPreview_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
InquiryReports objReport = new InquiryReports();
string vSelectionFormula = null;
ReportDocument objReports = (ReportDocument)MethodClass.ConnForReport(objReport);
vSelectionFormula = "{CompalintView.ComplaintStatus}='" + CboCompStatus.Text + "'";
InquiryRptViewer.SelectionFormula = vSelectionFormula;
InquiryRptViewer.ReportSource = objReports;
Session.Add("CR_Session",objReports);
}
```

In last, Don't forget to write these code on your page_load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
Session.Remove("CR_Session");
CboComplaintStatusFill();
}
else
{
InquiryRptViewer.ReportSource = Session["CR_Session"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
public static object ConnectionForReports(object objReport)
```

`objReport` is of type `object`

The type `object` has no notion of Database

So in short you're missing the appropriate type for `objReport`

you will either need to declare the appropriate type for this parameter

i.e.

```
public static object ConnectionForReports(SomeMagicalType objReport)
```

Or cast it to the appropriate type

```
((SomeMagicalType)objReport).Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo
```

**Update**

I've never used crystal reports so this is a shot in the dark

however id say your `SomeMagicalType` should be `ReportDocument`

i.e you might be able to get away with changing to this

```
public static object ConnectionForReports(ReportDocument objReport)
```

Comment: When i use the function as ReportDocument,
public static object ConnectionForReports(ReportDocument objReport)
 it shows me another error
logOnInfo = objReport.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo;

Comment: Object Reference Not set to instance of an object

Comment: Error is on above line

Comment: Ok can you update the question with the code your using to call ConnectionForReports, and add the new error your getting to the question and what line its occouring on thanks

Comment: It will also be useful to put the words Update to let people know you have progressed from the intial problem

Comment: i have used a datatype name ReportDocument,it works perfectly
`public static object ConnectionForReports(ReportDocument objReport)
{
logOnInfo = objReport.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo;
}
`

Comment: but when i use this method on a button event,
`protected void CmdPreview_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
frmInquiryReports objReport = new frmInquiryReports();
objReport = MethodClass.ConnectionForReports(objReport);
}`
it shows me error like: "The best overload method matche for ConnectionforReports(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument) has some invalid Arguements"

Answer (score -1):

It is not able to find ApplyLogInfo method on the db table as it does not exist.

I think what you want to achieve is as below -

```
 private void LogonToReport(string server, string database,
         string ID, string password)
      {
         TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
         foreach(Table table in Report.Database.Tables)
         {
            logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = database;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ID;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password;

            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
         }
      }
```